# C++ std method listing

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, std, xcode3.2

I am new to C++ and XCode.

I would like to know how I can get a list of available methods from `namespace` **std** or any other namespaces `#include`'ed in a **cpp** file., in a similar way you would do method scoping in Eclipse *(ctrl+space)*.

Thanks

Comment: With Xcode you use `Escape`, but it's auto-completion for C++ simply doesn't really work.

Comment: You are right, I get a message "No completions found". If I press Escape without std:: (namespace) XCode shows me the members from namespace std.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche Make your comment a answer so I can score you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xcode you use <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but it's auto-completion for C++ simply doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an editor e.g. Code::Blocks that gives you a list of all std:: -things defined in the current includes to a project. Just type `std::` and a list will popup.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on IDE you use. In Visual Studio and NetBeans `ctrl+space` works too. Also you can just type `::` operator and see what is aviable in current scope.